# iPad App - Deployment without needing the UDID

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a doubt. Please guide me. I am planning to create an iPad app, but I want to install this app on the iPad without using the UDID in my profile. I have checked the "Enterpraise Account", but without this approach (like sideloading apps on android) is there any possible way to do this? Are there any problem that may arise?

Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Your options are either AppStore or Enterprise account. With the enterprise account way having meny restrictions. 
The enterprise account will allow you to distributie the app to the register company only, if you do distribute the app to non employees of the company Apple will close down you account.

You could look at jailbreaking, but you won't reach as many user as you will when distributing your app via the AppStore.

Comment: Hi, Please clarify one more doubt. I have standard developer license(paid $99). whether I can use the same license for my enterprise account or I have to buy separate license for that? Please guide me

Comment: You will have to buy a separate license.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the closed nature of the distribution of apps within iOS, you don't have a choice.

The only way to load an application onto a device, without caring what the device ID is, is via the Enterprise programme or App Store. The Enterprise programme is like a controlled, secure, sideloading process (if we want to to have an analogy with Android), but is limited to distribution within an Enterprise only. The App Store means you have to publish the app to Apple, and follow their rules.

To get the app on the device, without using those two methods, you need to create an Ad-Hoc build, but this requires the device ID, as it'll cross-reference it with the provisioning profile provided. If the device ID is not linked with a provisioning profile for the application, the device will not let it run.

The unofficial way to load an app on a device without needing it's device ID is via a jailbroken device, but that's unreliable and requires the user to be tech savvy.

Answer (score 1):

NO, there is no way to distribute app via ad-hoc for any device(not having UDID) without Enterprise license.